# Cloud Files - Override Expires and Cache-Control headers that CDN sends to Browser but not the CDN's TTL

Tags: cdn, cache-control, cloudfiles, akamai

I'm trying to get a single file to be cached for 3 days on the Cloud Files CDN (Akamai) but then send the file to the browser with the headers:

```
Expires: Time Now..
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
```

I know Akamai has the `Edge-control` header for this... but I cant seem to set it on the Cloud Files website.

Does anyone know a good way to achieve this with Cloud Files?

#### Update:

I have submitted this on Rackspace's feedback site:
http://feedback.rackspace.com/forums/71021-product-feedback/suggestions/4014775-allow-akamai-s-edge-control-header-per-object

If anyone else wants this please vote for it :)

#### Update June 2014

My suggestion on the rackspace feedback site has been removed.
I'm chasing with support as to why this is.

Comment: Any progress on this?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot set TTL for individual objects.  You can set the X-TTL on your CDN Enabled container:

```
curl -XPOST -H 'x-auth-token: <your token>' -X 'x-ttl: 259200' <your cloudfilesCDN publicURL>/cdn-enabled-container
```

this will control how long the CDN caches objects in that container.

Comment: So you cant have the edge and browser having different TTL's?

I want to disable browser caching.